# How to display a web page with dynamic data using c++ and QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to display a web page using C++/QT with dynamic data.

1. If user clicks, the web page should be displayed
2. The web page should contains a table format data. The data will be read from the table using C++ and will be dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the HTML content of QWebView using `setHtml()` function. Have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#setHtml). Call it when the user clicks the button to load HTML.
To get the contents of loaded HTML code you can use two methods provided by [QWebFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebframe.html) inside your QWebView: 
`webview->page()->mainFrame()->toPlainText()` 
 
`webview->page()->mainFrame()->toHTML()` 
You will have to parse the HTML to read data from table shown in QWebView.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to First Question**

You can use **[QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html)** to display your start-up html using `QWebView::setHtml()` or  `QWebView::load()` function.

**Answer to Second Question**

Regarding this question, there can be multiple ways in which you can set dynamic data in your page.

One way is you can use **javascript** function to update your html table. Which you will insert in the html in `<script>` tag. Now you can pass data (read through c++) using following function..

```
webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(yourJavascript);
```

Well you will have to generate javascript function call string `yourJavascript` from the data read through c++.

But if you can retrieve your data from database in **JSON** format, it will be very easy for you. For example you can use **[QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/)** third party library to *parse* and *serialize* **JSON** data as per following..

```
QByteArray data;   // Say data arrived from the database is stored in this object.

QJson::Parser parser;
QVariantMap map = parser.parse(data).toMap();

// Now serialize it and pass it to javascript function as an argument..

QJson::Serializer serializer;
QString javaScript = "updateHtmlView(" + serializer.serialize(map) + ");";

webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(javaScript);
```

So now you can update your html table by reading that **JSON** object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at QWebView, 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html

Example from the website above

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView(parent);
    view->load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
    view->show();
```

Create this view in the event handler from where the User clicks and all should work fine.

Comment: I need to display a web  with dynamic data. I will get the data at run time which need to be displayed on the web page in a table format.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by dynamic data in this situation?